# How to make a text disapper under an image, after scrolling it up?

Tags: html, css, scroll, background-image, document-body

Is it possible to gradually hide the text from the website, after scrolling it up, under an image? Only by using HTML and CSS?

This is my `body` example:

```
<img src="./image.gif">
<p> some text to scroll up... </p>
<p> more text to scroll up... </p>
<p> even more text to scroll up... </p>
```

Comment: By definition you can't hide *beneath a background*...only elements,

Comment: since your are using fixed as background-attachment you can change it with an element where you apply position:fixed

Comment: image tag is an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
img{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
/* or like this */
#grad{
  position:fixed;
  left:300px;
  top:0px;
  height:150px;
  width:300px;
  z-index:10;
  background:linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}

body{
margin-top:170px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://29comwzoq712ml5vj5gf479x-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/default.svg">
<div id="grad"></div>

<p> some text to scroll up... some text to scroll up... some text to scroll up... some text to scroll up... </p>
<p> more text to scroll up... </p>
<p> even more text to scroll up... even more text to scroll up... even more text to scroll up... even more text to scroll up... even more text to scroll up... even more text to scroll up... even more text to scroll up... </p><p> some text to scroll up... </p>
<p> more text to scroll up... </p>
<p> even more text to scroll up... </p><p> some text to scroll up... </p>
<p> more text to scroll up... </p>
<p> even more text to scroll up... </p><p> some text to scroll up... </p>
<p> more text to scroll up... </p>
<p> even more text to scroll up... </p><p> some text to scroll up... </p>
<p> more text to scroll up... </p>
<p> even more text to scroll up... </p><p> some text to scroll up... </p>
<p> more text to scroll up... </p>
<p> even more text to scroll up... </p>
```